# Calculate $\det(p(A))$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant, jordan-normal-form

> Let $n \in \mathbb N$, $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ be nilpotent and $l\in \mathbb N$. Further, let $$p = \sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i A^i \in \mathbb C[t]$$ be a polynomial. Show that zero is the only eigenvalue of $A$. Then calculate $\det(p(A))$.

My approach:

Since A is nilpotent, there is a $k\in N$ with $A^k=0$. Let $\lambda $ a eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v$. Then, $$0=A^kv=A^{k-1}Av=A^{k-1}\lambda v=A^{k-2}A\lambda v=\lambda A^{k-2}Av=\lambda A^{k-2}\lambda v=\dots=\lambda^kv$$and therefore $\lambda^k=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=0$. Therefore $\lambda=0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$.

For the second part I thought to use that $A$ is similiar to $S^{-1}JS$ with $S\in Gl_n(\mathbb C^{n,n})$ and $J$ is a jordan block of size $n$. Then, $$\det(p(A))=\det(p(S^{-1}JS)=\det (\alpha_0I+\alpha_1S^{-1}JS+\dots+\alpha_nS^{-1}J^nS)=\det(S^{-1}(\alpha_0I+\alpha_1J+\dots+\alpha_nJ^n)S)=\det(\alpha_0I+\alpha_1J+\dots\alpha_nJ^n)$$ and since $J$ is upper triangular with zeros on its diagonal, we recieve $\det(p(A))=\alpha_0^n$.

Does this argumentation seems to be okay?

Comment: It looks very nice, yet the very last argument needs, imo, more explanation why the determinant of that sum $\;\alpha_0I+\ldots a_nJ^n\;$ is $\;\alpha_0^n\;$ ? +1

Comment: @DonAntonio $J^i$ is for any $i$ strict upper triangular with every time we multiply $J$ with $J$ its 'entries move one diagonal' higher. Thus the sum is strict upper triangular and so the determinant is just the product of the diagonal entries. But thanks for your comment!

Comment: In general, a nilpotent matrix is not similar to a Jordan block.

Comment: a nilpotent matrix in $C^{n,n}$ is not similiar to a jordan normal form? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I have a theorem that states: Let $A\in K^{n,n}$ nilpotent  with nilpotent Index $ n $. Then there exist S in $GL_n (K) $ such that $S^{-1}AS=J_n $ where $ J_n$ is a jordan block of size n to the eigenvalue zero.

Comment: Where is $l$ used?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo what do you mean? I do not understand your question

Comment: In the question, you write "$l \in \mathbb N$", but I don't see where the symbol is used.

Comment: Yes you are right, I missed something. The sum is from $i=0$ to $l$ instead of $n$. Does this will make any problems or is the proof still valid?

Comment: I think it does not matter, or?